# How to stop schedule publishing in weekends?

Tags: publishing, scheduled-tasks

I am using Sitecore.NET 7.2 (rev. 140228).

For my project schedule publishing is in place. In weekends I have a separate job which creates over 100k items and this job publishes all the items after creation programmatically. So, I want to stop my regular schedule publishing as my publishing struck as both publishing happening simultaneously in weekend.

Could anyone suggests how to stop my schedule publishing only in weekends?

Answer (score 13):

This can be achieved by updating your `Schedule` field on your task.

[image]

127 represents the days of the week, this task is meant to run. This only makes sense if you convert it to binary.

`127d = %01111111`

Each of the bits represent a day of the week. Like this.

```
-SFTWTMS
01111111
```

So to disable the tasks for the weekend, change it to:

```
-SFTWTMS
00111110
```

`%00111110 = 62d`

[image]

See also: [How to create Sitecore Scheduled Task](http://www.degdigital.com/insights/how-to-create-sitecore-scheduled-task/)

Answer (score 6):

Disable your default publishing  in web.config

```xml
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:00:00">
```

Override Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent

```xml
<agent type="YourMethod, YourClass" method="Run" interval="01:00:00" ><br>
  <param desc="source database">master</param>
  <param desc="target database">targetDB</param>
  <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">incremental</param>
</agent>
```

put your custom conditions in run method

```cs
public void Run()
    {
        DayOfWeek day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
        if (day != DayOfWeek.Saturday && day != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            this.StartPublish(this._languages);
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!